# fail2ban not banning but matches logs

Tags: fail2ban

I try to create a brute force protection with fail2ban. With the fail2ban test, it matches the logs I wanna match but with my test brute forcing the site with 7+ failed logins, it does not ban my ip address.

filter:

```
[Definition]
failregex = <HOST>:.*"POST /login.*" 200 .*$
ignoreregex =
```

jail:

```
[shop-brute-force]
enabled  = true
filter   = shop-brute-force
logpath  = /etc/exampleorg/shop/log/access.log
maxretry = 7
findtime = 60
bantime  = 900
ignoreip =
```

log example (anonymized with ..., 88.88.88.88 and example.org):

```
2022/04/01 08:09:25.413720 88.88.88.88:10729 - - [01/Apr/2022:08:09:25 +0000] "POST /login?target=%2Fshop%2F HTTP/1.1" 200 2192 "https://example.org/login?target=%2Fshop%2F" "..."
```

test:

```
Running tests
=============

Use   failregex filter file : shop-brute-force, basedir: /etc/fail2ban
Use         log file : /home/user/test.log
Use         encoding : UTF-8


Results
=======

Failregex: 3 total
|-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
|   1) [3] <HOST>:.*"POST /login.*" 200 .*$
`-

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [106] Year(?P<_sep>[-/.])Month(?P=_sep)Day 24hour:Minute:Second(?:,Microseconds)?
`-

Lines: 106 lines, 0 ignored, 3 matched, 103 missed
[processed in 0.02 sec]

Missed line(s): too many to print.  Use --print-all-missed to print all 103 lines
```

Answer (score 0):

> I try to create a brute force protection with fail2ban
> `failregex = ... 200 ...`

This is not necessarily a brute force attempt, because 200 is a regular response, that means OK... Normally codes like 401 or 403 would signal unauthorized attempts, or if the service answering with 200, it would write an additional log-entry in some log-file or journal (not necessarily into the `access.log`). But also another things are very questionable here, let alone theoretically one is able to brute force using another methods as `POST`.

> but with my test brute forcing the site with 7+ failed logins ...
> `Lines: 106 lines, 0 ignored, 3 matched, 103 missed`

You did not provided the whole log excerpt corresponding to this 7 attempts.
And `fail2ban-regex` find only 3 matches related to your `failregex` (which is not good at all, e. g. unanchored and has catch-all's, however never mind - the matches are not there). Probably it logs something other as a single log-line from your example, because your RE basically matches that.
Thus please update your question with whole log-excerpt corresponding all 7 attempts you did.

And last but not least, much better RE could look like that:

```
failregex = ^\s*<ADDR>:\d+ [^"]*"[A-Z]+ /login\b[^"]*" 200\b
```

However I'm still unsure you'd really use that (due to 200th problematic et al I mentioned above).

If it was only test (with 3 log-lines) and you really see all 7 log-lines in the real log, you can check this [FAQ for the possible reasons why fail2ban doesn't ban](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/wiki/How-fail2ban-works).
For instance it may be incorrect `backend` (set it to `auto` for file-related monitoring) or unsuitable ban-action or some error on fail2ban side (check also the fail2ban.log).